# Disable on angular chosen is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I have an issue with disabling the chosen tab when the page loads. My js code is like below.

```
(function() {
  angular.module('chosenExampleApp', ['localytics.directives']).controller('IndexCtrl',function($scope) {
      $scope.testProp = "hello";
      $scope.myPets = ['cat'];
      $scope.pets = {
        cat: 'Cat',
        dog: 'Dog',
        hamster: 'Hamster'
      };  
    })

}).call(this);
```

Html body is like below.

```
<body ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
    Disable <input type="radio" ng-model="testProp" name="radiotest" value="hello"/>
    Enable <input type="radio" ng-model="testProp" name="radiotest" value="hello1"/>
  <select
    multiple
    ng-model="myPets"
    ng-options="value as label for (value, label) in pets"
    chosen
    ng-disabled="testProp=='hello'"
    style="width:200px;">
  </select>
</body>
```

Since the value of testProp is set to hello, I am expecting the chosen to be disabled while the page loads. But its enabled when the page loads.Once I select the button enable and then select disable, its working fine. Please let me know how to solve this issue.

The Link to Plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KvGS7yd9qPWn9GIofXON)

Comment: It's working, what's your problem? The select IS disabled on load. Check http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/yrz7Lwn8/

Comment: Code is working. http://jsfiddle.net/tvbypttj/1/

Comment: Please find the image of the chosen attached at page load. If chosen is used properly the image will be like in the picture.

Comment: The issue is likely to be simple, however setting up a demo to test it is something I'm lazy to do now. If you could set up a plunker with chosen and `localytics.directives` directive then it would help.

Comment: Please find the link to plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/KvGS7yd9qPWn9GIofXON

Comment: @dfsq I have added the code in plunker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, looks like a bug in the directive, namely: it removes `disabled` attribute right before initializing Chosen plugin. This [line](https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen/blob/master/src/chosen.coffee#L49):

```
stopLoading = -> element.removeClass('loading').attr('disabled', false).trigger('chosen:updated')
```

is the problem. It should be:

```
stopLoading = -> element.removeClass('loading').attr('disabled', attr.disabled).trigger('chosen:updated')
```

You can patch source code or wait/fix it, I opened the issue [here](https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen/issues/131).

Here is fixed **demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/gFLbMpG93TtB9xQBNTfH?p=preview

Comment: NB!!!! With this temp fix please note all of your chosen elements will have to have an ng-disabled for this to work or they will be set to disabled by default. set ng-disabled="false" if you must.